# What is the most efficient way to search for a string regardless of spacing using Microsoft SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Currently I am using the if statement and listing all possible combinations.

```
IF string = 'L1' OR string = 'L 1' then do something.
```

I wonder if there is a better way? I know I can use the `replace` function but is that gonna be efficient to do on 100,000+ lines in a database. It is being used in a scalar-function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an index on `string`, then:

```
where string in ('L1', 'L 1')
```

can make use of the index and will be the most efficient method.

Otherwise,

```
where replace(string, ' ', '') = 'L1'
```

seems the most convenient.

I would, however, suggest that you fix the string in the database.  In fact, you can use a computed column and add an index on it:

```
alter table t add stringNoSpaces as (replace(string, ' ', ''))

create index idx_t_stringNoSpaces on t(stringNoSpaces)
```

Then the condition:

```
where stringNoSpace = 'L1'
```

will use the index and be happily efficient.  And, SQL Server will maintain the index whenever the `string` column is modified.

Comment: Love the computed column idea.

Comment: There may be cases where just using `PERSISTED` would gain the most benefit, by precomputing and storing the value but not creating a new nonclustered index. If table filter conditions will use your suggested index efficiently, then the index is the way to go, but if not (due to the usage patterns) then `PERSISTED` would speed up writes to this column a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of combinations of words to look for and you can deal with some latency then consider using SQL Full Text Search: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx

It's very easy to impact performance negatively with UDF's